# A doubt on Pascal's law

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

Many videos show that Pascal's Law, $\frac{F_1}{A_1}=\frac{F_2}{A_2}$ for bended connected tubes. Does it also apply for straight connected tubes?

Comment: you have not asked a question.  Please consider editing your statement.

Answer (score 1):

Pascal's law is valid for incompressible fluids regardless of the container the fluid may be in.